# How to wait with specific <script> to the time when $("input").change(function(){}); will be finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use output of

```
$("input").change(function(){});
```

to use in other script on page. How to wait with  execution to the time when change() will be finished?

Comment: explain the scenario.

Comment: Call whatever logic you need at the end of the `change` event handler. There's no way to know when all logic in associated event handlers has completed from outside the handler.

Comment: Put the code inside the callback function that you pass to ’change()’

Answer (score 0):

Stop the execution of the main scripts when you should wait and continue it at the end of your function. If needed, save the current state into a variable.

```
$("input").change(function(){
     //do callback stuff

     //...

     MainScript.continue();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the other script code in a function and use the below approach -

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Test input:
    <input type="text" name="testinput" />

</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").change(callback, function() {
            console.log('inside the click');
            callback('1');
        });

        function callback(val) {
          // other script wrapped in callback..
          console.log('Value received:' + val);

        }

    });
</script>

</html>
```